# MOSS 2007 Different master page for content pages

Tags: sharepoint-2007

How can I set a different master page for only 1 content page?
I've followed the steps here http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/change-the-current-master-page-HA010167165.aspx#BM3, but to no avail.

The content page is still displayed using the master page set in the Site Settings.

Answer (score 0):

That should work. Have you saved, checked in, and published the modified page?